# Can I deploy Meteor apps to CloudBees?

Tags: meteor, cloudbees

I would like to deploy Meteor version 0.7 and 0.8 up to CloudBees? what is the best way to do this and is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

This can be achieved using the "-t nodejs" command line option when deploying - as meteor can be deployed as a nodejs app.

The best way is to use "demeteorizer" to convert it to a plain nodejs app:

https://github.com/onmodulus/demeteorizer

Once you have the plain app - you can npm install and zip -r - the app directory - and deploy it normally on cloudbees as a nodejs app from there.